# Laravel schedule don´t send email

Tags: php, laravel, mailgun

i´m trying to send an email from the schedule of laravel, all the API configuration works in controllers, but in schedule not

```php
    public function handle()
    {
        $lateLoans = ReaderRecord::where('estado', 'atraso')->get();
        $stolenLoan = ReaderRecord::where('estado', 'robo')->get();


        foreach ($lateLoans as $lateLoan)
        {
            $loanDate = new Carbon($lateLoan['entrega']);
            $today = Carbon::today();

            $mailData = [
                'title' => 'Informe de préstamo',
                'name' => $lateLoan->reader['nombre'],
                'lastName' => $lateLoan->reader['apellido_paterno'],
                'book' => $lateLoan->record->book['titulo'],
                'idBook' => $lateLoan->record['id'],
                'days'  => $loanDate->diffInDays($today),
                'endDate' => $lateLoan['entrega']
            ];

            $email = $lateLoan->reader['email'];
            $name = $lateLoan->reader['nombre'];
            Mail::send('mail.loan.late', $mailData, function($message) use (&$email, &$name) {
                $message->to($email, $name)->subject('Atraso de entrega de préstamo');
            });
        }
    }
```

Comment: How are you testing the scheduler? With `php artisan schedule:run` or a conjob?

Comment: with `php artisan schedule:run`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don´t know why, but the solution was this

https://github.com/yabacon/paystack-php/wiki/cURL-error-60:-SSL-certificate-problem:-unable-to-get-local-issuer-certificate-(see-http:--curl.haxx.se-libcurl-c-libcurl-errors.html)

1. download the file https://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem
2. edit the `php.ini` and add this

```
   curl.cainfo = your\absolute\path\cacert.pem
```